# Azure Graph API giving error "Auth token does not contain valid permissions or user does not have valid roles"

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, office365api

I have been trying to list Microsoft Security Scores, following official instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-securescores?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
but I keep getting an error:

`Auth token does not contain valid permissions or user does not have valid roles.`

Auth token is being requested once the user has loged in and provided the consent to my registered application. Application has all of the required permission as described in the official [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-securescores?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): `SecurityActions.Read.All, Subscription.Read.All, User.Read.All`

Currently I am trying this in React.jS however I have tried this process in Postman and Node as well but I am still stuck.

```
const accessToken = await this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent({
    scopes: config.scopes
});
const securityScores = await getSecureScores(accessToken);
if(securityScores && securityScores.value){
    this.setState({
        securityScores: securityScores
    });
}
```

and scopes array looks like this:

```
scopes: [
    'Directory.Read.All',
    'AccessReview.Read.All',
    'offline_access',
    'Organization.Read.All',
    'Policy.Read.All',
    'profile',
    'SecurityActions.Read.All',
    'Reports.Read.All',
    'SecurityEvents.Read.All',
    'User.Read',
    'User.Read.All'
]
```

Comment: Did you check the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms? Check it contains the scopes. If it does, then it could be your user can't access that data?

Comment: @juunas yes I have, and it shows my token contains read access for SecurityActions.Read.All SecurityEvents.Read.All among other.

Comment: And I've confirmed the user is a global admin.

Comment: Are you able to share the full error body (with request ID and timestamp)?

Comment: `{"statusCode":403,"code":"UnknownError","message":"Auth token does not contain valid permissions or user does not have valid roles.","requestId":"e0940a60-c89a-4cfb-8d46-af2bb417667b","date":"2020-01-28T09:29:48.000Z","body":"{\"code\":\"UnknownError\",\"message\":\"Auth token does not contain valid permissions or user does not have valid roles.\",\"innerError\":{\"request-id\":\"e0940a60-c89a-4cfb-8d46-af2bb417667b\",\"date\":\"2020-01-28T14:29:48\"}}"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. This error occours when you are using [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).

There is not a `wids` field in the access token obtained through the implicit flow. Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims), it may not be present in tokens due to token length concerns.

There are two workarounds.

1. Once the response mode is changed to `response_mode=form_post` the id
   token, and access token if requested, are sent as a POST request and
   contain the wids claim which allows the Graph API security endpoints
   to be used.
2. Do an OBO call to get a token for Graph, then call graph to learn
   what they wids or roles are on the token. You can also do OBO to get
   an id_token which should have those claims in it.

See a previous discussion [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/677). And you need to pay attention to rayterrill's [answer](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/677#issuecomment-489865107) and hpsin's [answer](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/677#issuecomment-564265842).